# Como revalidar datos almacenados en caché?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Estoy trabajando con Next 12. Tengo una funcion fetch que almacena datos y los cachea.

```
const results = await fetch(url, {
  cache: "force-cache"
})
```

Si yo estuviera trabajando con Next.js 13 podria hacer:

```
const results = await fetch(url, {
  cache: "force-cache",
  next: {
    revalidate: 10
  }
})
```

Y cada 10 segundos los datos deberian actualizarse. (https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating)

El problema es que el proyecto esta muy avanzado y migrar a Next.js 13 puede ser un trabajo grandisimo. Alguien sabe alguna manera de revalidar los datos luego de un tiempo determinado con JavaScript puro?

Comment: Lo que buscas [esta acá](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)

Comment: @Marcos lo que sucede es que no es una llamada que se hace una sola vez al cargarse la vista, creo que en ese caso me serviria. Esto es una llamada a la API de next, se hace cada vez que el usuario realiza un cambio de filtros de busqueda. En la api de next tengo una llamada al backend. Si intento configurar el Cache Control desde la api no funciona. En mi llamada fetch, en el componente (el codigo de esta pregunta), solo me funciona ``force-cache`` pero quisiera limpiar esos datos cada 1 hora, por ejemplo.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/584923/next-js-13-res-revalidate-revalidatepath-con-la-nueva-opcion-de-response